# How to get unique records from 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have 3 tables and I am trying to get unique results from all 3 tables (including other columns from each table).

I have tried union approach but that approach only works when I have single column selected from each table.

As soon as I want another corresponding column value from each table, I don't get unique values for the field I am trying to get.

Sample Database and query available here as well: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1b9a6/10

Here is the example tables i have created.

```
CREATE TABLE TABLEA
(
    id int, 
    city varchar(6)
);
    
INSERT INTO TABLEA ([id], [city])
VALUES
    (1, 'A'),
    (2, 'B'),
    (3, 'C');

CREATE TABLE TABLEB
(
    id int, 
    city varchar(6)
);
    
INSERT INTO TABLEB ([id], [city])
VALUES
    (1, 'B'),
    (2, 'C'),
    (3, 'D');

CREATE TABLE TABLEC
(
    id int, 
    city varchar(6)
);
    
INSERT INTO TABLEC ([id], [city])
VALUES
    (1, 'C'),
    (2, 'D'),
    (2, 'E');
```

**Desired result:**

```
A,B,C,D,E
```

Unique city from all 3 table combined. By unique, I am referring to DISTINCT city from the combination of all 3 tables. Yes, the id is different for common values between tables but it doesn't matter in my use-case if id is coming from table A, B OR C, as long as I am getting DISTINCT (aka UNIQUE) city across all 3 tables.

I tried this query but no luck (city B is missing in the output):

```
SELECT city, id 
FROM 
    (SELECT city, id 
     FROM TABLEA
     WHERE city NOT IN (SELECT city FROM TABLEB 
                        UNION 
                        SELECT city FROM TABLEC)
     UNION
     SELECT city, id 
     FROM TABLEB
     WHERE city NOT IN (SELECT city FROM TABLEA 
                        UNION 
                        SELECT city FROM TABLEC)
     UNION
     SELECT city, id 
     FROM TABLEC) AS mytable
```

Comment: Aren't city B should not be unique because table A also have it? Can OP describe more about the definition of 'UNIQUE' ?

Comment: Hi @T.Peter By unique, I am referring to DISTINCT city from the combination of all 3 tables. Yes, the id is different for common values between tables but it doesn't matter in my use-case if id is coming from table A, B OR C, as long as I am getting DISTINCT (aka UNIQUE) city across all 3 tables.

Comment: I get it. But it will be better if we can know what is your desire result with this sample database. like should it be (A,E) or (A,B,C,D,E) etc. @kuml2

Comment: Hi @T.Peter Desired result is two columns - city (A,B,C,D,E) and id (corresponding id to the city)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this. As this should give you distinct city with there first appear id:

```
select distinct min(id) over(partition by city) id, city  from (
select * from TABLEA
union all 
select * from TABLEB
union all
select * from TABLEC ) uni
```

Comment: Hi Peter thank you for the query. This is certainly a right approach where I am trying to go. I am trying to make sure if I understand the approach correctly. If id field was a simple varchar field (not an int value), how that will change the query? in that case, i am assuming min(function) won't be applicable?

Comment: `min` will also work with varchar. but if you afraid about this  you can try to change the datatype first using `convert` .

Answer (score 0):

You got the right idea, just wrap the UNION results in a subquery/temp table and then apply the DISTINCT

```
WITH TABLEE AS (
SELECT city, id FROM TABLEA
UNION
SELECT city, id FROM TABLEB
UNION
SELECT city, id FROM TABLEC
)
    
SELECT DISTINCT city
FROM TABLEE
```

Comment: Hi Nick thank you for the answer. I did try similar approach with UNION but i need corresponding id as well (DISTINCT city and corresponding id). as soon as I add id the query, i get unique SET of city and id with repeated city. I am looking for unique / distinct city with corresponding id.I hope that makes sense (if I explained it correctlly)?

Comment: In your example city 'C' appears in all 3 tables and have 3 different ids - 1, 2 and 3. Which id would you want in this case? There is 1 unique city in this case but 3 unique city-id pairs.